# Is this sentence grammatical?

Tags: grammar

"In Figures 1 and 2, the results of the studies A and B are respectively presented."

I'm not sure if the "respectively" position is correct.

Comment: "Figure 1 presents the results of study A, and Figure 2 the results of study B." Why complicate life with algebra?

Comment: "Figures 1 and 2 show the results of studies A and B respectively."

Comment: Why this question is flagged with off-topic? I learn a lot from this kind of question as it helps me to learn about the sentence structure.

Answer (score 3):

This is the standard approach that I am familiar with:

> The results of studies A and B are presented in Figures 1 and 2, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

"Respectively" is usually best avoided, whether it is grammatical or not. The word forces the reader to pause and make sure she understands which goes with what. It interrupts the flow of your prose.

I would agree that TonyK's formulation looks and sounds somewhat better, but I would change the sentence to read, "The result of Study A is presented in Figure 1 and that of Study B in Figure 2."

And even if you disagree, for goodness' sake don't use it with more than two linkages: "A, B, and C are shown in 1, 2, and 3, respectively." Your reader will come to a screeching halt as he goes back to make sure he has the sequence right.

Always make things as easy as possible for your reader. Style is much more important than grammar in this case.

Answer (score -1):

More usual is:

> In Figures 1 and 2, the results of the studies A and B respectively are presented.

Note the word order.

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence is grammatically correct.

According to the [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are%20respectively%20presented%2C%20respectively%20are%20presented%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20respectively%20presented%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crespectively%20are%20presented%3B%2Cc0) the position of 'respectively' can be both before and after the verb.